# Doubt on Signal Processing Step

Tags: discrete-signals, signal-analysis, quadrature

I am using a **Radar Sensor**. So applying Signal Processing on the Radar Sensor Data. PrevSample and PastSample are  Radar IQ samples for a present and previous Sweep **detecting tiny movement**. In the source code I have some doubts that . Here I am adding the portion of Python Code . Can anyone please explain the following signal processing, and the significance of that, please describe what each term indicate

```
import numpy as np

Envelope   = np.abs(PresentSample)
Delta = PresentSample * np.conj(PreviousSample)
PhaseWeights = np.imag(Delta)
Weights = np.abs(PhaseWeights) * Envelope
DeltaDist = np.dot(Weights, np.angle(Delta))
DeltaDist *= 2.5 / (2.0 * pi * sum(Weights))
```

Present and prev samples are 1D array consisting of iq samples.
For each processing .
Is Delta is cross correlation ?
Please give explanation for rest of the codes
Why multiply the  DetltaDist ?

DeltaDist is the tiny movement, which is used to store in a Buffer. I am asking the signal processing logic of this code/algorithm. I know the code and the functions **conj**, **imag**, etc...   I just want to know  for example why we take conjugate product/ why we take imaginary part like that

Comment: do you know what the result `DeltaDist` is used for. We can tell you what each of these operations are (but honestly, `conj`, `imag`, `abs` and `angle` are all well-documented and also self-explanatory, so not quite sure what the value for you would be; also, askiung about that many things, it's a bit broad), but we can't tell you what they're *for* without understanding the application here. What kind of signals are in the IQ signal? What is the thing your system does, overall?

Comment: but: no. Delta is not cross-correlation; it's the conjugate product of `PresentSample`and `PreviousSample`.

Comment: Sorry I dont understand the problem and this community is not here to explain you the code you found somewhere which you are trying to use. You dont tell us where your doubts are and what you would expect from the code? Neither you dont tell us whether the results are fulfilling the expectation. I would not consider this question to be in the scope of DSP.SE.

Comment: Welcome to SE.SP! As others have said, please give us more information about what you are trying to achieve with the code. Also, please include code that has all the included and used libraries. For example, your code should probably have `import numpy as np`. Please edit your question with this extra information.

Comment: Ok. I am using a Radar Sensor. So applying Signal Processing on the Radar Sensor Data. PrevSample and PastSample are  Radar IQ samples for a Sweep.    DeltaDist is the tiny movement, which is used in a Buffer. I am asking the signal processing logic of this code. I know the code and the functions conj, imag, etc...   I just want to know  for example why we take conjugate product/ why we take imaginary part

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what your code is doing, but my understanding is:

```
Delta = PresentSample * np.conj(PreviousSample)
```

gets the difference between the previous sample and the present one. This might look like:

$$
\Delta = e^{j\omega n} \cdot e^{-j\omega (n-1)} = e^{j \omega}
$$

provided the signal you're interested in is like a complex exponential signal.

Then

```
PhaseWeights = np.imag(Delta)
```

is taking the imaginary part of

$$
e^{j\omega} = \cos(\omega) + j\sin(\omega).
$$

If $\omega$ is small enough, then
$$
\Im (\Delta) =  \sin(\omega) \approx \omega
$$
because $\sin(x) \approx x$ for small $x$.

It's not clear to me why this is a good thing.

Comment: yeah, I'm just as confused about the taking of the imaginary part as "importance" of anything. This would make (some) sense for say, BPSK lying on the imaginary axis, but not for a radar signal. Rohith really needs to define in more detail what "radar signal" they're actually considering.